# Bash split string by string and check if date is older than 1 day

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following output stored in a variable.

```
Time created: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 17:57:52 GMT
```

Now, I would like to split the date string and check IF date is older than 1 (day) / 24 (hours) / X (days)

> Sun, 08 Nov 2020 17:57:52 GMT

Below you can find my script:

```
full_time_created="Time created: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 17:57:52 GMT"
IFS='Time created:' read -ra VALUES <<< "${full_time_created}"
short_date_create=$(echo ${VALUES[@]} | xargs)

echo ${VALUES[@]} # Return a broken string
Sun, 08 Nov 2020 17 57 52 GM
```

How can I do that in Bash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `date(1)` and shell arithmetic expansion, something like

```sh
if (( $(date +"%s") - $(date --date="$(sed 's/^[^:]*: //' <<<"$full_time_created")" +"%s") > 24*60*60 )); then
    echo "Created time is older than one day."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cut to get date string then using `gnu date` command to parse and get to previous day like this:

```sh
date -d "$(cut -d : -f2- <<< "$full_time_created") -1 day"
Sat Nov  7 12:57:52 EST 2020
```

And then to get to get EPOCH value:

```sh
date -d "$(cut -d : -f2- <<< "$full_time_created") -1 day" '+%s'
1604771872
```

You can get EPOCH value of previous date from today using:

```sh
date -d '-1 day' '+%s'
1607167689
```